# Is it possible to show the k8s network topology using kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I installed the minikube in my CentOS 7.7 Server.

there are several pods in it:

```
[dele@att root]$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide
NAMESPACE              NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP           NODE       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
kube-system            coredns-f9fd979d6-4p6xg                     1/1     Running   1          23h   172.18.0.2   minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system            etcd-minikube                               1/1     Running   0          22h   172.17.0.2   minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-apiserver-minikube                     1/1     Running   0          22h   172.17.0.2   minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-controller-manager-minikube            1/1     Running   1          23h   172.17.0.2   minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-proxy-4k468                            1/1     Running   1          23h   172.17.0.2   minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-scheduler-minikube                     1/1     Running   1          23h   172.17.0.2   minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system            storage-provisioner                         1/1     Running   2          23h   172.17.0.2   minikube   <none>           <none>
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper-c95fcf479-k7zpn   1/1     Running   1          23h   172.18.0.3   minikube   <none>           <none>
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-5c448bc4bf-f9swt       1/1     Running   1          23h   172.18.0.4   minikube   <none>           <none>
```

but I can not see a clear network topology diagram, is it possible to show the network topology using the `kubectl`?

Comment: What do you expect to see?

Comment: I want to see the network architecture.

Comment: I have no image of the network connection.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible out of the box with kubernetes (and kubectl) as far as I know.
With additional software in your cluster I know about three possiblities with visualization:

1. [Istio](https://istio.io/) has the possibility to visualize the communication within the mesh with kiali (For reference: https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/kiali/)
2. The second option is [spekt8](https://github.com/spekt8/spekt8)
3. [Weavescope](https://www.weave.works/oss/scope/) comes with agents that gather data and visualizes them

Despite these options others could exist and I would really like to see more options because not everyone wants to add **Istio** and accept the performance impact just to visualize the pod/network landscape.

And as far as I understand **spekt8** it's more about the visualization of relations between Kubernetes resources than about network topology visualization.

**Weavescope** needs cluster administration rights therefore it isn't advisable to make it public accessible without setting up some form of authentication.